# Webview Authentication challenge in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

How to display the Authentication Challenge in UIWebView using Swift? When i load the authenticated URL's into web view , it is throwing error 401 and without asking me to enter Credentials. i searched many questions in stack overflow but not helped much.

please suggest how to handle authenticated URL's into Web view.

Answer (score -1):

you can implement Authentication Challenge delegate methods by handling request as below

```
 let pageUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string:urlstring)!
 let  webViewrequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: pageUrl, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 15)
 NSURLConnection(request: webViewrequest!, delegate:self)!
    webview.loadRequest(webViewrequest!)
```

Comment: Thank you.. i have done this authentication challenge using NSURLconnection  delegate methods